# Can't make my Github workflow runner to pick a very simple job

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I got this very basic workflow set up in my project's .github/workflows/main.yml file. As you see is really basic, it's the simplest option I could find as an example (I tried other options, none of them work).

```
name: main
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  Run-npm-on-Ubuntu:
    name: Run npm
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm help`
```

I keep getting the following: Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...

Is there a way to debug it at least? Even if I cancel the workflow, the log file not giving me any information.
Possibly something wrong with my configuration, but not sure what.

Expecting the runner to pick up my workflow.

Comment: `Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...` means it is scheduled. Its not a problem on your side.

Comment: I left it for half an hour, it just keeps waiting, I don't think that's normal.

Comment: Do you have any self-hosted runners configured for that project?

Comment: Nope, I thought this will use Github hosted runners, the configuration above is taken from the Github documentation website.

Comment: I think I just give up on it, I can't even figure out if the issue is within my repo or with the runners on Github's side. The yml file I shared is the exact copy of the example from the official documentation. I don't understand what can go wrong.

Comment: Disregarding the erroneous trailing backtick at the end of your code snippet, the workflow looks fine at a glance.  Can  you verify that you have a `master` branch and that the workflow has been committed to it?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at your GitHub Billing page to ensure you haven't exhausted your Actions minutes quota - https://github.com/settings/billing.

Comment: For completeness: Are you running this on github.com or on your own GitHub Enterprise Server? Because the latter will (most likely) not have that label available.

Comment: It works now, I think I sort of misunderstood something here, I thought that by cancelling a pull request, its associated action instances will also get cancelled/stopped. It seems, that it doesn't happen that way. Last night I started to receive a bunch of notification emails regarding some pull requests created and cancelled days ago. So I went to my Actions section, after scrolling all the way down on the list I noticed, that there are still some Action instances queued, it look like some of them were hanging there for quite a while and the were holding up the queue. Cancelling them helped.